# Canvas How to convert getImageData to toDataUrl format

Tags: html, canvas

How to convert getImageData to todataUrl

```
code lines: 
var data = ctx.getImageData(150,200,200,100);
var data = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL('image/gif');
```

First situation: 1 parameter x space, 2 y space, 3 and 4 x,y example image: `http://postimg.org/image/lfogtwjn7/` so i got croped image data 200px x 100px
Second situation i get full image toDataUrl: `document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL('image/gif');`

**How i can get cropped image like a `getImageData(150,200,200,100)` but toDataUrl format**
Maybe somebody have other offer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use additional canvas draw image in there and then get `toDataURL()`

```
var destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 150,200,200,100);
var dataUrl =destCtx.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Comment: u mean like this?
var sourceCanvas = ctx.getImageData(820,300,500,200);
ctx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
var data = ctx.toDataURL('image/gif');

Comment: there's overload for `drawImage` that allows to spacify width and height and clip image http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: Good answer. Note that `.toDataURL` does not accept the gif mime type.  You can use .png (the default) or .jpg.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in all Browsers. Instead of `drawImage` I have to use `putImageData`. Browser is FF52

Answer (score 2):

`toDataURL()` Method should be used with HTML Canvas-element and not with canvas context. So you have to do like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasId');
var dataUrl =canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```